# Using dd command and running out of space while cloning drive to img

Tags: linux, hard-drive, dd, cloning

I have a problem with drive cloning. 
Im using dd on damaged disk with bad sectors trying to make an image from it. Im booting computer with Live Linux CD .

Damaged disk: sda 146GB   (NTFS)
External drive: sdb 300GB (NTFS)

After running the command below im running out of space on disk sdb.

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/sdb1/hdd.img bs=4096 conv=noerror,sync
```

**The question is why im running out of space on disk sdb ?**

**UPDATE: There is 300 GB of free space on partition sdb1**

Comment: To be clear, you *do* have 146G of space available on `sdb`, right?

Comment: Yes, I have 300GB of free space on disk sdb

Comment: It is okay, that your sdb drive has 300 GB capacity, but your sdb1 partition has also enough free space for that image file?

Comment: Can you add the output of df -h?

Comment: Yes because there is only 1 partition on disk sdb (whole 300GB)

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/sdb` is a device special that represents the disk drive; it isn't a filesystem, but you've tried to use it as one.

Instead, try this:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=4096 conv=noerror,sync
```

Comment: I dont want to clone drives one to one, i want to clone sda to image file (because sdb is USB disk drive). Im changing the question since it could be misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it looks to me like a problem in NTFS driver (problem with large files).

Did you mount the NTFS partition using ntfs-3g? Also, could you provide us with full `dd` output?